# Visual Studio 2012 MVC 3 - Ação do botão não funciona

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Fiquei alguns anos sem usar o visual studio. Agora fui tentar novamente e me deparei com um problema.

Criei um novo projeto web no visual studio 2012, usando a opção ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application. Pedi um novo web form e coloquei nele um Button e um Label. Dai a intenção é, ao clicar no botão, ele colocar uma frase qualquer no Label.

Pra começar, cliquei duas vezes no Button. Dai o visual studio já criou pra mim a função do evento Click no botão. Dentro do evento, coloquei a ação:

Label1.Text = "Ola Mundo";

Não acusa nenhum erro, mas quando rodo o projeto e clico no botão, simplesmente não acontece nada. Nunca tive esse problema nas versões anteriores do visual studio. Nessa versão, e devido ao MVC, há algo diferente que eu deva fazer pro botão executar a ação quando clicar nele???

Comment: Pode ser que você não está rodando a compilação mais recente do seu projeto. Tente Clicar em Build -> Clean Solution e tente novamente.

Comment: Obrigado Tony, mas mesmo assim não foi. Realmente estranho. Depois vou tentar eu outro PC pra ver se o problema pode ser aqui. Descobrindo o que é, eu posto. Obrigado.

Comment: Também estranhei o fato de ele colocar o código C# dentro do mesmo documento ASPX (In page), sendo que nas versões anteriores, ele colocava o código C# numa classe separada (Code Behind). Teria como "obriga-lo" a guardar o código C# num arquivo separado?

Comment: OK. Você poderia deixar fazendo o download do Visual Studio 2013 (estável) http://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx. Ou se preferir o Visual Studio VNext (em desenvolvimento).

Comment: Notei que quando inicio um projeto Web Application normal (não MVC), dai ele trabalha com o code behind, mas quando o projeto é MVC3 não.

Comment: Aproveita que você está retomando com Visual Studio e usa uma versão mais recente como a 2013.

Comment: Posta na pergunta o codigo ASPX e o Code Behind

Comment: Galera, instalei o VS 2013. Mas agora quando tento rodar o projeto, aparece a mensagem:
A exibição em '~/Views/Home/Index.aspx' deve derivar de ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl ou de ViewUserControl<TModel>.
Alguma dica???

Comment: Começa um novo projeto, já com o novo template que vem com o Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Agora me ocorreu uma coisa. Eu tinha o VS 2012 antes. Porém antes de instalar o 2013, desinstalei o 2012.

Comment: O que ocorre é que o MVC, assim como a própria internet, evoluiu muito e mudou bastante ao longo das suas versões. Por isto o recomendado é usar a versão mais recente do Visual Studio e MVC.

Comment: Cria um novo projeto no VS 2013 e vai comparando com o seu e veja o que mudou em cada um dos arquivos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não vai funcionar, simplesmente. O MVC não usa Code Behind. É outro paradigma e outra forma de usar botões e eventos pro *Controller*. Não vale a pena explicar todas as diferenças nesta resposta.

[Na wiki da tag](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-mvc/info) [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) há tutoriais e documentos que você ler para começar.