# Atualizando os registro da tabela dinamicamente

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou com o seguinte cenário: Tenho uma View (tipada ex.: `produto {codigo, descricao, quantidade, qtdeRecebida}`) onde é carregado uma tabela. Nesta View, além da tabela, eu ainda possuo um textbox e um botão. Quando o usuário informar o produto e clicar no botão eu preciso executar um método que está na classe Produto (CodeBehind) que faz o incremento da `qtdeRecedida` e atualiza a tabela de forma dinâmica. Qual a solução pra isso? Alguém tem algum exemplo semelhante?

Obs.: Sou iniciante e este cenário está sendo desenvolvido em ASP.Net MVC 4.

Comment: [MVC com Code Behind?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38152/visual-studio-2012-mvc-3-a%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-bot%C3%A3o-n%C3%A3o-funciona/38160#38160)

Comment: Aliás, qual a necessidade dessa atualização dinâmica? Não é possível fazer tudo com HTML e validar no *Controller*?

Comment: "Quando o usuário informar o produto": como o usuário informa o produto? Existe um checkbox para cada linha da tabela? Por favor, coloque o código atual das sua View, pelo menos a parte relevante. Se possível do Controller também.

Comment: É um processo de conferencia da quantidade recebida dos produtos... dinamicamente a atualização será mais rápida consequentemente o processo de conferencia também. O usuário tem que ver que a quantidade do produto está sendo incrementada. Se a pagina recarregar a cada produto informado o processo demora mais.

Comment: Existe uma tabela carregada com uma lista de produto. Nesta view existem um textbox e um button. Ao pressionar o botão o sistema irá capturar o produto informado no textbox em seguida irá percorrer a lista de produtos e se encontrar o produto informado, o campo qtdeRecebida desse produto respectivo é incrementado. Nesse ponto a tabela tem que ser atualizada pra que o usuário veja as alterações

Comment: @ReinaldoGuilherme Não era melhor editar a pergunta ao invés de colocar isso tudo como comentário? Eu diria que um passo inicial seria o Ajax, mas ainda não entendi por que você precisa ir no *Controller* pra saber se um produto existe ou não. [O recomendado é você usar algo como um `autocomplete` do jQuery UI ou coisa do tipo](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).