# Como fazer um post back (refresh) no MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Eu sou novo no MVC e sou acostumado com web forms e os eventos dos controles que causam o postback e atualiza a pagina.

Preciso fazer essa atualização na pagina no MVC depois de um javascript ser acionado.

No codigo abaixo eu consegui chamar o metodo que eu preciso mas ele não faz o postback (reflesh) da pagina de forma automatica, nem usando o $post nem usando o $ajax

Para fazer a atualização da pagina estou usando o location.reload(); que só faz o postBack(reflesh) somente no final da execução do $post ou do $ajax.

Preciso de um "efeito" igual o de um "asp:button" que o onClick já pisca a tela na hora e executa no servidor o código c#.

Bom eu espero ter conseguido passar a informação correta do que preciso.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var totalPaginas = parseInt('@ViewBag.TotalPaginas');
var paginaAtual = parseInt('@ViewBag.PaginaAtual');
var registrosPorPagina = parseInt('@ViewBag.RegistrosPorPagina');

$('#divPaginacaoUm').bootpag({

    total: totalPaginas,
    page: paginaAtual,
    maxVisible: registrosPorPagina,
    leaps: true,
    firstLastUse: true,
    first: '<',
    last: '>',
    wrapClass: 'pagination',
    activeClass: 'active',
    disabledClass: 'disabled',
    nextClass: 'next',
    prevClass: 'prev',
    lastClass: 'last',
    firstClass: 'first'

}).on("page", function (event, num) {

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Paginacao", "Pesquisa")',
        data: { 'num': num },
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            location.reload();
        }
     });

    $.post('@Url.Action("Paginacao", "Pesquisa")', { num: num }, function (data) {
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

Comment: Acho que na arquitetura MVC você deve chamar o controler, enviando o viewmodel, o controler vai fazer o que tem q ser feito com o viewmodel e retornar a view (que pode ser a mesma) com um novo viewmodel, essa view pode ser trabalhada com esse novo objeto, deu para entender?

Comment: Eu consegui entender o que vc quis dizer, mas não sei como fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que vale a pena te explicar as diferenças arquiteturais entre o Web Forms e o MVC. [Daria pra começar por aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38152/visual-studio-2012-mvc-3-a%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-bot%C3%A3o-n%C3%A3o-funciona/38160#38160), mas eu vou esmiuçar um pouco mais os conceitos que você colocou.

> Eu sou novo no MVC e sou acostumado com web forms e os eventos dos controles que causam o postback e atualiza a pagina.

O *postback* não existe no MVC. Isto porque a arquitetura contempla a representação por estados ([REST, como chamamos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST), e não estamos falando de REST API e Web API, mas sim da definição de REST). O *postback* veio numa época que uma aplicação Web Forms não implementa isso. Você tem a página e o *Code Behind* interagindo com a página, seja lá quantos eventos a página e o *Code Behind* tenham em comum.

Já no MVC não existe essa interação entre página e código. A página (*View*) é resultado de uma requisição que já terminou. O que se faz, como no caso do Ajax, é abrir requisições novas, mas o código do servidor não fica "ligado na página" o tempo todo como é no Web Forms.

> No código abaixo eu consegui chamar o método que eu preciso mas ele não faz o postback (refresh) da pagina de forma automática, nem usando o $post nem usando o $ajax.

Sim, justamente porque isso está fora de propósito. Você quer fazer uma paginação Ajax, mas recarregando o `location`. Não faz sentido.

Em primeiro lugar, o ASP.NET MVC [possui um componente de paginação](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/). Ele faz esse trabalho pra você.

Em segundo lugar, o *callback* `success` apenas recarrega a página. É um esforço inútil. Você não popula nada. Não altera nada em tela. O uso do Ajax está descontinuado.

Procure testar este pacote de paginação numa *View* estática. É melhor que seguir por este caminho que você começou.

> Preciso de um "efeito" igual o de um "asp:button" que o onClick já pisca a tela na hora e executa no servidor o código c#.

Melhor você fazer outra pergunta pedindo paginação em Ajax para ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Obrigado @Cigano Marrison Mendez, eu ainda não tinha comentado sua resposta pelo fato de eu não ter entendido ela tão bem quando vc a publicou, agora como eu melhorei na linguagem eu já consigo entende-la melhor.